# Sample unique rows from a column in a dataframe without replacement

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a `dataframe` in which the first column contains unique row `ID`s, and the second column contains values that are often not unique between rows. Below is a simplified example using `iris` data:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(iris$Sepal.Length)
> id <- rownames(df)
> df <- cbind(id, df)
> colnames(df) <- c("id", "Sepal.Length")

> nrow(df)
[1] 150

> length(unique(df$id))
[1] 150

> length(unique(df$Sepal.Length))
[1] 35

> head(df,10)
   id Sepal.Length
1   1          5.1
2   2          4.9
3   3          4.7
4   4          4.6
5   5          5.0
6   6          5.4
7   7          4.6
8   8          5.0
9   9          4.4
10 10          4.9
```

I would like to randomly sample from `df$Sepal.Length` without replacement so that the rows in the sampled data have unique row ID values.

```
> set.seed(22)
> df_sample <- df[sample(df$Sepal.Length, 10, replace=FALSE),]
```

However, `replace=FALSE` still gives me rows with duplicate IDs:

```
> duplicated(df_sample$id)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Is there a way to sample this data without replacement so that it returns unique rows? I am trying to specifically sample `df$Sepal.Length` because I would also like to supply a probability vector for this column. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies if this was unclear -- I am showing a simplified example, but I need to specifically sample df$Sepal.Length because I would eventually like to supply a probability vector for this column. I will update the question to state this more explicitly.

Comment: Maybe  `df[sample(length(df$Sepal.Length), 10, replace=FALSE),]`. If not, maybe you aren't explaining the problem clearly.

Comment: @Suren Yes this works, thank you! This is similar to Shree's answer.

Comment: Yes,  Shree's answer is similar to mine. I wouldn't have commented if he has given it before me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way -

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(iris), Sepal.Length = iris$Sepal.Length)

df_sample <- df[sample(nrow(df), 10, replace = F), ]

duplicated(df_sample$id)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sample_n()` and `sample_frac()` functions from `dplyr` to do just this with a data frame. It makes sampling much easier.

```
sample_n(iris, 100, replace = FALSE)
sample_frac(iris, .75, replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going with Shree's answer since it requires minimal changes to my existing code, but I'll keep this in mind in the future.